Missing libgd2-xpm dependency attempting to install rexxgd-oorexx in Noble Numbat
Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu Unity 24.04.1LTS and I'm attempting to reinstall all of the programs and utilities I had in Jammy. I got everything to install except the rexxgd-oorexx product due to an unresolved dependency. I can't seem to find libgd2-xpm anywhere. Can someone help?

Can you be more specific about what it is that you are trying to install, and how? According to the libgd2 changelog, the "xpm vs noxpm library dichotomy" was "got rid of" more than a decade ago - I don't think a separate libgd2-xpm package has been available in Ubuntu since around 14.04

Someone else pointed that out in a different forum. SOMEHOW I was able to install rexxgd-oorexx on Jammy two years ago. I don't know how that could be unless I did something "special" which I didn't write down.  This is the page for the program:  https://rexxgd.sourceforge.net/index.html which hasn't been updated since 2012. I've also written to the developer via the support page but have yet to hear back from him. He is still active according to his own home page at https://www.rexx.org/

Mark Hessling posted an updated deb file that installs successfully on 24.04.1LTS. If anyone is interested, you can get it here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/rexxgd/files/
